# Jquery decimal mask for latitude

Tags: jquery, decimal, mask

I want to put a decimal mask on a textbox.
I want the for mat to be 999.99999 (three digits to the left of the '.' and 5 to the right.

I want to allow the negative sign '-' at the start

so we can input -245.45218 for example 
I tried using this:

```
 $("#latitude").decimalMask("999.99999");
```

But this does not allow the '-' sign to be placed at the begining

I also tried

```
$("#latitude").decimalMask("#999.99999");
```

But it is not working.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you provide a link to the plugin

Comment: http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/decimalmask this is the link. I don't mind what plugin I use if you know so other one that can help let me know. thanks

Comment: I provided an answer that alternatively uses a negative sign for geolocation coordinates.. did it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin allows you to create your own mask element.. 
https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput

```
$.mask.definitions['~']='[-]?';
$("#latitude").mask("~999.99999");​
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/MKKWd/

Comment: Your link is dead

Comment: My answer was 6 years old but thanks for letting me know.  Updated the answer with the github link.